# What's the meaning of "Corrected for chance"?

Tags: clustering, model-evaluation

I've been trying to understand `Adjusted Rand index`. I understand `Rand index`, and the definition of `Adjusted Rand index` is it's the corrected-for-chance version of the Rand index.

What does that really mean? I tried to search the meaning but was unable to find any clear explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the definition of ARI in terms of the Rand index RI.

Correction for chance means that the RI score is adjusted in a way that a random result ('result by chance') gets a score of 0.

On certain data sets, a random result can score an RI if 0.9 - on other data sets this would be a good results. The ARI is this more interpretable, as random results always score 0.